# How to read JSP a file from WEB-INF into a variable for later "printing"

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I would like to know how is possible to read a file placed in WEB-INF direct into a variable.
My intent is to load (and process a page) into a var, than save it to a file and besides that, use the same html result to be displayed (like included) directly into another JSP.

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [RequestDispatcher.include()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) method and buffered response. The latter you'll have to write yourself by extending [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) and overriding `getWriter()` / `getOutputStream()` methods to return an internal buffer (based on `StringWriter`, for example). In your servlet, do something like:

```
MyBufferedResponseWrapper buffer = new MyBufferedResponseWrapper(response); // wrap real response
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("path_to_your_jsp").include(request, buffer);
String output = buffer.getOutput();
```

Comment: interesting, but is request os reponse available in struts action?

Comment: In Struts both are passed as parameters to execute() method: http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html. In Struts2 both are available from ServletActionContext: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/how-can-we-access-the-httpservletrequest.html

Answer (score 1):

You can hide jsp pages under WEB-INF which can be <jsp:included>.

Do you expect a caching benefit?

Comment: I would like to read a file just like that

    <c:set var="body">
    <jsp:include page="...jsp"/>
    </c:set>

    <cout value="${body}

but inside a struts action, what mean no jsp directive. just regular java.